# Use nested ng-repeat outside the element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

everyone, I've a scenario like this...

```
$scope.flags = {
            'porIdade': {
                'text': 'Por idade',
                'flags': {
                    'meses1a3': '1 a 3 meses',
                    'meses4a7': '4 a 7 meses',
                    'meses8a12': '8 a 12 meses'
                }
            },
            'sexo': {
                'text': 'Sexo',
                'flags': {
                    'menino': 'Menino',
                    'menina': 'Menina'
                }
            },
            'estacao': {
                'text': 'Coleção',
                'flags': {
                    'menino': 'Inverno',
                    'menina': 'Verão'
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically I need to put, for example: porIdade.text into the panel-heading into a DIV
and populate the children inside the UL. I don't know how to use ng-repeat for this. This is the html.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="leftColumn">
    <div class="panel-heading">PARENT</div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Child1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Child1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Child1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Child1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so, if I set something like this:
    PARENT

this will create 3 rows with panel-heading. So, to solve this I need something like...

```
<ng-repeat start here (key,val) in flags>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="leftColumn">
    <div class="panel-heading">PARENT</div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat children>{{child.text}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</ng-repeat finish here>
```

ANy suggestions ? I can't use a DIV before the panel :( so, this suggestions is not valid. It's causes a weird behaviour with the bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a nested `ng-repeat` like this: (I've removed classes to keep the concept more readable)

```
<div ng-repeat="data in flags">
  <div ng-bind="data.text"></div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.flags" ng-bind="item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```